# Changing color of the text that is being typed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

Is it possible to change color of the text that is being typed into a form?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6669946/3103677

Answer (score 2):

to color only the text that is being typed, you can add :focus on your selector

```
input:focus, textarea:focus {
color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is! To change color of the input text that is being typed in a form include this in your css file:

```
input, select, textarea {
color: red !important;
}
#example {
color: #0000ff !important;
}
```

Comment: Hey Marko, don't use `!important` unnecessarily. check MDN to know when exactly to use `!important`

Comment: Well I have Material Design and it's overwriting some classes so that's why I included it..