# Semantic-UI theming focused input text color

Tags: gulp, less, semantic-ui, theming

It's my first time theming Semantic-UI and I can't find an option to modify the focused input text color. I have been able to change every color but this one. I am using the default theme.

---

### Here is my site.variables so far:

```
/*******************************
     User Global Variables
*******************************/

/*-------------------
       Fonts
--------------------*/

@fontName: 'Montserrat';

/*-------------------
      Base Sizes
--------------------*/

/* This is the single variable that controls them all */
@emSize: 14px;

/* The size of page text  */
@fontSize: 14px;

/*-------------------
    Brand Colors
--------------------*/

@primaryColor: @orange;
@secondaryColor: @white;

@segmentColor: @gray;

/*-------------------
        Page
--------------------*/

@pageBackground: @black;

/*-------------------
       Links
--------------------*/

@linkColor: @orange;

/*--------------
   Form Input
---------------*/

/* This adjusts the default form input across all elements */
@inputBackground: @darkGray;

/* Input Text Color */
@inputColor: @orange;
@inputPlaceholderColor: darken(@textColor, 75);
@inputPlaceholderFocusColor: darken(@textColor, 45);

/*-------------------
    Focused Input
--------------------*/

/* Used on inputs, textarea etc */
@focusedFormBorderColor: @primaryColor;

/* Used on dropdowns, other larger blocks */
@focusedFormMutedBorderColor: @primaryColor;

/*-------------------
        Page
--------------------*/

@textColor: @white;

/*-------------------
      Site Colors
--------------------*/

/*---  Colors  ---*/
@orange: #f05026;
@black: #101113;
@gray: #2f2d2e;

/*---  Dark Colors  ---*/
@darkGray: #141314;
```

I also tried to modify the `@focusColor` property in the `input.variables`, but it didn't work either.

### Here are the inputs in their different states:

[image: unfocusedplaceholder]

---

[image: focusedplaceholder]

---

[image: focusedwriting]

---

[image: unfocusedwriting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless this was changed since the last time I used Semantic-UI, I don't remember that being a variable you can change. You would be best off using some CSS to accomplish what you want. See below:

```
input:focus {
  color: red
}
```

[CSS Input field text color of inputted text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669846/css-input-field-text-color-of-inputted-text)